# Extract lines with a matching pattern in log file delimited by some characters

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep, tcl

I have a log file in this format.

```
MATNR -- 0000000000090933887
Some text 
in 
between
*****Return Message** Successfully processed
some
more 
text 
blah 
blah
-----------------------------------------
MATNR-000000000000090934206
some
text 
in 
between
*****Return Message** Successfully processed
some more text
blah 
blah
between
--------------------------------------------
```

This is how my log file is structured. I plan to fetch the MATNR line and the message on the line **** Return Message***. In the log each new entry is delimited by ------------.Is there a way using grep,sed,tcl program which can efficiently perform this action for us.

I tried attempting this by using grep using z option. But i am still not sure how i can attempt to fetch matching lines within those.Below just gives the MATNR which is surrounded by some lines.

```
grep -zPo '(\n-+\n)\K(.|\n)+?MATNR(.|\n)+?(?=\n-+\n)'
```

Expected output is

```
MATNR -- 0000000000090933887
*****Return Message** Successfully processed
MATNR-000000000000090934206
*****Return Message** Successfully processed
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Expected Output should be:

MATNR -- 0000000000090933887
*****Return MEssage** Successfully processed
MATNR-000000000000090934206
*****Return Message** Successfully processed

Comment: `grep -E '^(MATNR|\*{5}Return)' filename`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `awk` should do the job:

```sh
awk '/^MATNR/ {m=$0} /Return Message/ {print m, $0}' file

MATNR -- 0000000000090933887 *****Return Message** Successfully processed
MATNR-000000000000090934206 *****Return Message** Successfully processed
```

Comment: Yes. file is placeholder for the filename which is to be processed by awk.

Comment: This is what I'm getting using GNU `awk`, `gawk`, using your code: `MATNR-000000000000090934206 *****Return Message** Successfully processed` (i.e., only one line).

Comment: Yes that's right. I have also attached generated output in my answer. @CarlosPascual: Do you mean this output is wrong?

Comment: I think the command is supposed to print all the matching patterns of lines. We are supposed to get all those matching patterns in the output.

Comment: @anubhava. Reading the input I see `MEssage` in one line but `Message` in other. That's the problem.

Comment: @CarlosPascual: I still don't see the problem (see comment from OP below question on expected output) unless Karan shows a different expected output in question.

Comment: @anubhava. Reading the input, I see the problem: `MEssage` in one line and `Message` in another!!

Comment: Sorry anubhava.I got confused. Your command is working according to my requirements.Its perfect.

Comment: @CarlosPascual The output is supposed to have "Return Message" lines. The expression for the match is correct as shared by abubhava.Sorry as I didn't convey the expected output correctly. I will re-edit the question.

Comment: with `/Return M[eE]ssage/`  there is not problem. All correct. Excuse me @anubhava.

Comment: @Karan. Reading the input data (not the output) you give, first appears the word `message` written `Message` and `MEssage`.

Comment: I have made the corrections on the post. Now the input and the output is aligned.

Comment: `awk '/^MATNR|Return M[Ee]ssage/' file` OR `grep -iE '^MATNR|Return Message' file` will give output in different lines.

Answer (score 0):

In Tcl, you'd do this (assuming you're piping the input in on standard input and writing it to standard output) when printing just matching lines:

```
 while {[gets stdin line] >= 0} {
     if {[string match "MATNR*" $line] || [string match -nocase "*Return Message*" $line]} {
         puts $line
     }
 }
```

To print the lines between those markers as well (a task that `grep` isn't good at):

```
 set printing false
 while {[gets stdin line] >= 0} {
     if {[string match "MATNR*" $line]} {
         # Start of interesting sequence
         puts $line
         set printing true
     } elseif {[string match -nocase "*Return Message*" $line]} {
         # End of interesting sequence
         puts $line
         set printing false
     } elseif {$printing} {
         # Middle of interesting sequence
         puts $line
     }
 }
```

It's not quite the shortest way to write that, but I think it's pretty clear.

Comment: You'd do something pretty similar in Python or awk; having a boolean variable for “am I printing anything” makes solving the problem pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE '/^MATNR/{:a;N;/^-+$/M!ba;s/\n.*\n([*]{5}Return Message[^\n]*).*/ \1/Ip}' file
```

Turn off implicit printing `-n` and make regexp easier on the eye `-E`.

Gather up lines starting with `MATNR` and ending in a line that contains only `-`'s.

Pattern match for `*****Return Message` and if found print the desired format.

EDIT:

Since the OP has amended the question, this might be suffice:

```
sed -n '/MATNR/h;/Return Message/{H;g;p}' file
```

Comment: I think this would work catching the MATNR and the string return message within the block ending with ---. However, I never considered a case if there is an error and we never get a successful return message within the block.